# Error al intentar decodificar un mensaje mandado con Azure IoT Hub en Python

Tags: python, azure

Muy buenas, estoy intentando enviar un un mensaje C2D con el SDK de Python de Azure IoT desde mi computador hacia una Raspberry. He programado ya una detección de objetos y la idea es que cuando el objeto se detecte se envíe un mensaje mediante Azure IoT Hub a mi rasp para actuar según lo que yo le diga. He llegado al punto de enviar y recibir ya el mensaje, el detalle es que se envía como cadena de bytes, es decir, por ejemplo: b'ON'. he intentado decodificarlo a string de varias formas, pero simplemente no la puedo manipular, siempre que intento modificar el mensaje que recibo me aparece la siguiente excepción.

```
Exception caught in background thread.  Unable to handle. ['azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_handler_manager.HandlerManagerException: HandlerManagerException(\'HANDLER (_on_message_received): Error during invocation\') caused by AttributeError("\'Message\' object has no attribute \'decode\'")\n']
```

Llegue a rendirme e intentar crear una condicional con el Bytearray pero tampoco he podido crear el condicional, por ejemplo lo que muestro a continuación.

```
if message == b'ON':
     print('algo')
```

Simplemente lo ignora, aunque si haya enviado ese mensaje, no entra al condicional. Apreciaría un montón cualquier tipo de ayuda.

La función en donde envío el mensaje desde mi computador es este:

```
def iothub_messaging():
try:
    # Create IoTHubRegistryManager
    registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)
    print ( 'Sending message... ' )
    data='ON'
    registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID,data)
    input("Message send\n")
except Exception as ex:
    print ( "Unexpected error {0}" % ex )
    return
```

y el código en donde recibo el mensaje es el siguiente, dejo una muestra de como estaba intentando decodificar el mensaje que se envía. El cual el ultimo intento fue con .decode()

```
def message_handler(message):
print("Message received:\n")
message=message.decode()
print(message)
def main():
print ("Starting the Python IoT Hub C2D...")
# Instantiate the client
client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
print ("Waiting for C2D messages, press Ctrl-C to exit")
try:
    # Attach the handler to the client
    client.on_message_received = message_handler
    while True:
        time.sleep(1000)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("IoT Hub C2D Messaging  stopped")
finally:
    # Graceful exit
    print("Shutting down IoT Hub Client")
    client.shutdown()
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El parámetro `message` que recibes no es una cadena de bytes como pareces suponer (ya que le estás aplicando el método `.decode()`, el cual solo existe para cadenas de bytes).

En cambio es una instancia de la clase `Message`, que tiene varios atributos y métodos que deberías aprender a usar. [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-iot-device/azure.iot.device.message?view=azure-python) está la documentación oficial.

Según esa documentación hay un atributo llamado `data` que contiene el *payload*, es decir, los bytes realmente enviados por el dispositivo. Así que creo que ese es el atributo que te interesa en este caso. Puedes probar el código siguiente:

```
def message_handler(message):
  print("Message received:\n")
  print(message.data)
```

Si lo que se vuelca es una cadena de bytes (que reconocerás porque tiene una `b` delante de las comillas), entonces podrás hacer `message.data.decode()` para convertirlo en cadena normal. La documentación no deja claro el tipo del atributo `data`. Cabe suponer que sea una cadena de bytes pero no estoy seguro de si la librería la habrá convertido ya en cadena de caracteres, por lo que mejor antes hacer el experimento que te propongo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu valiosa explicación, ha funcionado tal cual lo propones. Ahora todo está más claro y por ello te lo agradezco infinitamente:) Saludos!